# Side-by-side configuration exception / VC++ runtime issue with SQL CE and Vista

Tags: visual-c++, windows-installer, sql-server-ce, windows-vista

I've installed my app with a private deploy of SQL CE 4.

After installing and launching on Vista I get

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files[edit]\sqlceme40.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.4148" could not be found.

I understand this is a VC++ Runtime issue but I can't find any clear answer how to resolve. Some say dependency is VC++ 2008, others say I need a manifest, etc. I use WiX to install merge module `Microsoft_VC110_CRT_x64.msm` for supporting a C++/CLI component also used in the app. Shouldn't that supply a later VC++ runtime that SQL CE can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL CE is bound to a particular version of the VC++ runtime so giving it v11.0 isn't sufficient; it needs v9.0.

Comment: Thanks. I added to the installer the Microsoft.VC90.CRT folder from the private deploy along with the contained .manifest and.dll and this fixed the issue for me.